# Specifying name when uploading to Wolfram Cloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I use utility below to share my notebooks to the cloud. One downside is that they show up in the list as UUD's and have `Name: Unnamed` in the hover status. Ideally there would be some kind of connection to the notebook I snapshotted it from, any suggestions?

```
deploy:=Module[{result,notebookPath},
notebookPath=$MachineName~StringJoin~":"~StringJoin~NotebookFileName[];
Print[notebookPath];
result=CloudDeploy[SelectedNotebook[],Permissions->"Public",SourceLink->None];
CopyToClipboard[result[[1]]];
result
];
```

[image]

Update: based on the answer, I modified my deploy as follows. This prints full local path of the notebook before saving to cloud, and uses filename as the name of cloud object.

```
(* Deploys current notebook, returns URL object *)
deploy:=Module[{result,notebookPath,notebookFn},
notebookPath=$MachineName~StringJoin~":"~StringJoin~NotebookFileName[];
notebookFn=FileNameSplit[NotebookFileName[]][[-1]];
Print[notebookPath];
result=CloudDeploy[SelectedNotebook[],CloudObject[notebookFn],Permissions->"Public",SourceLink->None];
CopyToClipboard[result[[1]]];
result
];
```

Another update: the recipe above will overwrite previous snapshots of the same notebook. Modify to include timestamp as part of name:

```
(* drops filename extension if present *)
dropExtension[fn_]:=(
toks=StringSplit[fn,"."];
If[Length[toks]>1,
StringRiffle[toks[[;;-2]],"."],
fn]
)
(* Deploys current notebook, returns URL object *)
(* TODO: add support for notebooks with no name (current gets StringSplit failed) *)
deploy:=Module[{result,notebookPath,notebookFn,uniqueFn,url,url2},
(* print out machine name + path + date *)
notebookPath=$MachineName~StringJoin~":"~StringJoin~NotebookFileName[];
notebookFn=FileNameSplit[NotebookFileName[]][[-1]]; (* just get basename *)
notebookFn=dropExtension[notebookFn];
uniqueFn=StringJoin[notebookFn,"_", timeString, ".nb"];
Print[notebookPath];
Print[DateString[]];
(* todo, also upload and link current notebook? *)
result=CloudDeploy[SelectedNotebook[],CloudObject[uniqueFn],Permissions->"Public",SourceLink->None];
url=result[[1]];
url2=URLShorten[url];
CopyToClipboard[url2];
url2
];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify a `CloudObject` like so:

```
CloudDeploy[SelectedNotebook[],CloudObject["Your Name Here"],...]
```

Comment: One gotcha I discovered, using notebook filename as CloudObject name will overwrite all results of all CloudDeploy instances from this notebook.